# Login/post to WordPress using Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, wordpress, cocoa

I checked out their API, but I didn't recognize anything, and saw nothing for Objective-C. Could someone guide me in the right path? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Searching for "Objective-C Wordpress API" gives me plenty of promising results. Do they not work for you?

Comment: Yes, I found what I was searching for. Sorry for stupid question then. For those who are curious of an example: http://ios.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/1.3_release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress doesn't have any specific Objective-C library as far as I know. It implements a few XML-RPC interfaces, so you'll just want to get an Objective-C XML-RPC library and talk to it through that.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the source code for their iOS app too if you want to see how they do it as well.

http://ios.wordpress.org/development/